# Python variable with dictionary bind issue

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a problem with dictionary. See samples.

```
dict1 = {"key1" : "value1","key2" : "value2"}
tempdict1 = dict1
dict1.pop("key1")
print(dict1) #returns {"key2":"value2"}
print(tempdict1) #returns {"key2":"value2"} also.
```

The dict1 works as expected but the tempdict1 also have the same value as dict1.

I am using Python 2.7.

Thanks!

Comment: `tempdict1 = dict1` does not create a copy. See the duplicate on how to create a copy correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you copy **the reference** th the dictionary, not the dictionary itself. Instead of:

```
tempdict1 = dict1
```

you should write

```
tempdict1 = dict(dict1)
```

to create a copy that you can alter independently.

Comment: prefer use [`deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy)
this will help only on one level of dictionary. 
`d1 = {'a': {'b':3}, 'c': 4};d2['a'].pop('b')` will change also the `d1` object

Comment: Yeah of course bit since the example shows strings and strings are immutable, there is "second level" so to speak.